# Formatting my data from a file;

Tags: c

This is how the data file looks.

```
strain condition exp.no t6 t24
ST1 wt exp1 1.77 7.60
ST1 wt exp2 1.58 7.39
ST1 wt exp3 1.78 7.57
ST1 wt exp4 1.82 7.60
ST1 wt exp5 1.59 7.59
```

I want to print the data as such:-

```
strain-----condition-----exp.no----t6--------t24
ST1-------wt--------------exp1------1.77----7.60
ST1-------wt--------------exp2------1.58----7.39
ST1-------wt--------------exp3------1.78----7.57
ST1-------wt--------------exp4------1.82----7.60
ST1-------wt--------------exp5------1.59----7.59
```

With the dashes representing spaces. I only managed to print the lines as strings individually and have no idea how format it as such.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char DATA[1024];
FILE *fbacteria;


if ((fbacteria = fopen("bacteria.exp", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
}

   while(!feof(fbacteria)){

 fgets(DATA,1024,fbacteria);
 puts(DATA);
    }
     fclose(fbacteria);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: `while(!feof(fbacteria)){` is definitively wrong.

Comment: If you want people to help you, please use proper formatting. Here's a [webpage](http://prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting) I wrote about correctly formatting C code.

Comment: Better as `while(fgets(DATA, sizeof DATA, fbacteria) != NULL) { puts(DATA); }`

Comment: You could extract each field with `strtok`, then print each with a format width specifier, such as `printf("%9s", token);`

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of the code? I'm not very proficient in C at the moment.

Comment: @MaxDenner please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can do it. I altered the input data a bit to show how the columns line up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>                 // added library file

int main(void)                      // corrected signature
{
    char data[1024];                // changed from all upper-case
    FILE *fbacteria;
    char *tok;
    int align[] = { -10, -11, -10, 8, 8 };    //column width and alignment left/right
    int column;

    if ((fbacteria = fopen("bacteria.exp", "rt")) == NULL)   // added "t" for MSVC
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fgets(data, sizeof data, fbacteria) != NULL) {     // feof is a no-no
        column = 0;
        tok = strtok(data, " \t\r\n");          // split the string at any of these chars
        while(tok != NULL) {
            printf("%*s", align[column], tok);  // * is placeholder for field width arg
            column++;
            tok = strtok(NULL, " \t\r\n");      // use NULL after first call
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fbacteria);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
strain    condition  exp.no          t6     t24
ST1       wt         exp1         11.77    7.60
ST1       wt         exp2          1.58    7.39
ST1       wt         exp3          1.78    7.57
ST12      wt         exp4          1.82  117.60
ST1       wt         exp5          1.59    7.59
```

The code assumes there will be no more than 5 columns of data. You could extend the `align` array to cover it, or use alternative way.

Comment: Was it you who asked this Q before and deleted it?

Comment: I haven't deleted a post before, so I don't believe so.

Comment: Oh there was a very similar question recently.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to print a string, replacing every space with 7 dashes:

```
void printDash(char *line)
{
    while (*line) {
        if (*line == ' ')
            printf("-------");
        else
            putchar(*line);
        *line++;
    }
}
```

You might call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
    char s[1024];

    while (fgets(s, 1024, f))  // loop through every line in the file
        printDash(s);          // print each line, replacing each space with dashes

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are there to show how it should be space-formatted in vertical columns.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP stated "I want to print the data...With the dashes representing spaces." This function replaces spaces with dashes, so it fulfills the request.

Comment: OP has accepted your answer, but if a number were `11.77` instead of `1.77` it won't align them.

Comment: Correct but given how I worded my question it does answer it.

Comment: @MaxDenner ...or did it?